# Grub rescue, unable to boot windows

Tags: linux, windows, boot, multi-boot

I have windows vista and backtrack Linux installed on my dell PC. I wanted to uninstall backtrack so I delect the partition, but when I try to boot widows again, the grub rescue> shown up. I can't boot a grub rescue disk onto the PC because the optical disk is broken.

What can I type in grub rescue> to repair windows boot manger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was definitively the wrong way, Dude! Before deleting or formatting Linux partitions, you'll need to remove Linux boot loader from system startup!

Now you can only start from Windows DVD and try to fix the boot MBR.

Boot using setup disc and enter into "Recovery Console" by pressing "R" key, select your Windows installation and enter Administrator password. If you don't have any password, press Enter key. Now run following command:

fixmbr

Press "Y" to confirm and type Exit to exit from recovery console.

Comment: I can't boot any CD, the internal optical disk have been broken for a long time

Comment: Never mind, create a bootable USB stick. Use other PC to create bootable Windows 7 / Vista / Whatever USB flash drive

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix the boot record.

In general grub (and almost all bootloaders) are 2 parts. The first is a very small and sits on one of the first sectors of your disk (physical sectors), the other is a bit bigger and sits in a partition.

The first part manages somehow to mount the second and hands of to it.

Because you destroyed that second part it has no idea what to do and drops you into rescue.

The correct way to fix this is to boot by some means a recovery media for windows (preferably the version you have though others may work) and fix the MBR. The command is fixmbr.

Another alternative is to install another linux to have grub.

Yet another is to use supergrub on a usb stick.

And yet one more ... in the grub rescue prompt:

```
root (hd0,X)
makeactive
chainloader +1
```

X is the number of the partition windows is installed (if first 0, if second 1, etc)

NOTE: This will not fix your bootsector but allow you to launch windows and nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions [here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/2011/12/.../doc-how-to-put-rescatux-into-a-usb/) to install [Rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/) on a bootable USB drive. Rescatux is a GNU/Linux  and eventually also Windows) rescue cd. Rescatux comes with Rescapp, a wizard that will help you fix your bootloader. Simply tell it to fix your Windows MBR. It's really simple.

I had the exact same problem 5 years ago and this was the only thing that worked.